# Initialize dict with only some of a list

Tags: python

I want to have a `dict` that maps from a list of items to sets of other things and I want to initialize this dict with an empty `set` and the best I can come up with is this:

```
mapping = dict()
for item in listOfItems:
    if item == "SomethingIDoNotWant":
        continue
    mapping.update({item:set()})
```

But this doesn't feel very pythonic. Is there a way of doing this with list comprehension that isn't impossible to read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most comprehensive way seems to be:

```
mapping = {item:set() for item in listOfItems if item != "SomethingIDoNotWant"}
```

As noted by [Peter DeGlopper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2337736/peter-deglopper) in the comments, for Python versions 2.6 and earlier there is no dict comprehension, and you need to do:

```
mapping = dict((item,set()) for item in listOfItems 
                            if item != "SomethingIDoNotWant")
```

Comment: Note that dict comprehensions are available on 2.7 and 3.x, but not 2.6 or earlier. For those you need `dict((item, set()) for ...)`

Comment: I didn't even know there was dict comprehension! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.7 and above you may use dict comprehension

```
mapping = {key: None if key == "SomethingIDoNotWant" else set() for key in listOfItems}
```

Note, that this solution will include a key "SomethingIDoNotWant". If that key is not required the solution is even simpler and is already described in other answer(s) around.

Comment: Dict comprehensions are good, but this does not produce the same end results as the OP's iterative code. For one thing, you have the comparison reversed (the OP wants sets for items that do not equal the flag value, not for values that do). For another, the OP's original code has no entry at all for the unwanted value, not None.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper You are right. I was already adding comment to my answer about including the unwanted key. And yes, I got lost in those negatively expressed conditions. Thanks.